# Unsubscribe from observable timers that emit only once necessary?

Tags: node.js, typescript, rxjs, observable, rxjs-observables

In my program, I have a few `timer(1000).subscribe()` instances as well as some `timer(1000, 1000).subscribe()` parts.

I was experiencing some memory leak issues and was wondering if I could alleviate those by unsubscribing from timers. Unsubscribing from recurring timers seems straight forward and necessary, but **do I also have to unsubscribe from timers that only emit once?**

The second part of my question is if there is a better way to unsubscribe from the emitting timer than to put it into a variable like so:

```
const myTimer = timer(1000).subscribe(() => {
    myTimer.unsubscribe();
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: You don't have to do `myTimer.unsubscribe();` like this. For details see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38008334/angular-rxjs-when-should-i-unsubscribe-from-subscription https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/the-best-way-to-unsubscribe-rxjs-observable-in-the-angular-applications-d8f9aa42f6a0 https://medium.com/@benlesh/rxjs-dont-unsubscribe-6753ed4fda87

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`timer` will complete itself after one emission, so there's no need for unsubscribe
For the alternative way to unsubscribe you can use the subscription instance. By using that, you benefit from storing all subscriptions and unsubscribe all with one call.

```
subs=new Subscription();
subs.add(timer(1000).subscribe())
subs.unsubscribe()
```

Comment: in the ex above `take(1)` would seem much easier to use though

Comment: As I mentioned in answer. Timer don’t need unsubcribe. The unsubscribe code is to show you an alternative way for handling unsubscriptions